# Eclipse Information Popup

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, fedora

i have a problem in Eclipse that the "help" popup is dark and i can't read the options.

Any one know how to fix it?

```
SO: Fedora 24 with Cinnamon.
Eclipse Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved editing the eclipse.ini on the Eclipse installation folder and Adding the line:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```